# Update Table with Duplicates

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

My Table, #MetaData looks like this

```
Table_Name Element        Join_prefix
Incident   hold_reason    h
Incident   impact         i
Incident   incident_state i
Incident   notify         n
Incident   severity       s
Incident   state          s
Change     impact         i
Change     incident_state i
```

I want to update the join_prefix where it is the same, to the first 2 characters of the element, within the Table_Name. So the table looks like

```
Table_Name Element        Join_prefix
Incident   hold_reason    h
Incident   impact         im
Incident   incident_state in
Incident   notify         n
Incident   severity       se
Incident   state          st
Change     impact         im
Change     incident_state in
```

I've been using the following sql but it updates all the rows

```sql
update #MetaData
set join_prefix=substring(element,1,2) 
where exists(
    select [Table_Name],[Join_prefix]
    from #MetaData 
    group by  [Table_Name],[Join_prefix]
    having count(join_prefix)>1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to use an updatable CTE. Within the CTE you can use a windowed `COUNT` to count how many rows have the same prefix, and then update those rows:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES('Incident','hold_reason   ',CONVERT(varchar(4),'h')),
            ('Incident','impact        ',CONVERT(varchar(4),'i')),
            ('Incident','incident_state',CONVERT(varchar(4),'i')),
            ('Incident','notify        ',CONVERT(varchar(4),'n')),
            ('Incident','severity      ',CONVERT(varchar(4),'s')),
            ('Incident','state         ',CONVERT(varchar(4),'s')),
            ('Change  ','impact        ',CONVERT(varchar(4),'i')),
            ('Change  ','incident_state',CONVERT(varchar(4),'i')))V(Table_Name,Element,Join_prefix)
GO
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Element,
           Join_prefix,
           COUNT(Join_prefix) OVER (PARTITION BY Join_prefix) AS C
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
UPDATE CTE
SET Join_prefix = LEFT(Element,2)
WHERE C > 1;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery is not correlated to the outside, so it always returns true. You need a `WHERE`

> Note that `exists` doesn't need to select anything, you can `select 1`.
> Also `count(*)` and `count(non_null_value)` is the same

```sql
update m1
set join_prefix = substring(element, 1, 2) 
from #MetaData m1
where exists (select 1
    from #MetaData m2
    where m2.join_prefix = m1.join_prefix
    group by m2.Table_Name, m2.Join_prefix
    having count(*) > 1
);
```

A better method would be an updatable CTE

```sql
with CTE as (
    select *,
        cnt = count(*) over (partition by m.Table_Name, m.join_prefix)
    from #MetaData m
)
update CTE
set join_prefix = substring(element,1,2) 
from #MetaData m1
where t.cnt > 1;
```